# TensorFlow, custom C++ op, use existing MatMul

Tags: c++, tensorflow, blas

I want to write a custom op (in C++), both for CPU and GPU (in CUDA).
It's pretty straight forward, except: How do I call BLAS (s)gemm (in both cases, for CPU and GPU)?

I looked a bit through the `LSTMBlock` op ([lstm_ops.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9153b897c4dfb8685d78397e22c1acd5ff24d40a/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops.h), [lstm_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9153b897c4dfb8685d78397e22c1acd5ff24d40a/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops.cc), [lstm_ops_gpu.cu.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9153b897c4dfb8685d78397e22c1acd5ff24d40a/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops_gpu.cu.cc), [blas_gemm.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9153b897c4dfb8685d78397e22c1acd5ff24d40a/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.h), [blas_gemm.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9153b897c4dfb8685d78397e22c1acd5ff24d40a/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/blas_gemm.cc)), and that seems to use Eigen for the CPU case, and `ctx->op_device_context()->stream()->ThenBlasGemm()` in the GPU case.

It would have been nice if the `ThenBlasGemm` API would have been also available for CPU but it seems to be GPU only. (Maybe I should do a feature request for this?)

But using Eigen for the CPU case (or also gemm in general) does not seems to be the best thing to do in all cases. I was looking through the `MatMul` op ([matmul_op.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2204f80a811ba53d969f3debe22f70ed06e12c79/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.h), [matmul_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2204f80a811ba53d969f3debe22f70ed06e12c79/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc), [mkl_matmul_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2204f80a811ba53d969f3debe22f70ed06e12c79/tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_matmul_op.cc), [gemm_functors.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2204f80a811ba53d969f3debe22f70ed06e12c79/tensorflow/core/kernels/gemm_functors.h)) and there seem to be many special cases (e.g. using gemm or gemv, using MKL if available, etc). I don't think it would be a good idea to try to replicate all of this (which would mostly be to copy & paste the code).

Is there any easy to use API for `matmul` which I can use in my custom op? (Maybe I should do a feature request for this?)

Or maybe, is there a way to call the existing `MatMulOp::Compute` inside my own op?

Comment: @nick: Ideally I want to use the same what TF uses (esp what TF `MatMul` uses), otherwise the behavior (performance) might be a bit unexpected, and also I do not need to care about how to initialize LAPACK/ATLAS or whatever.